# Restriction of command

Tags: javascript, qualtrics

I wrote a JS code for progress by press "Enter" (in Qualtrics):

```js
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function() {
    var qid = this.questionId;
    document.onkeydown = function(event) {
        console.log('keydown', event);
        if (event.which == 13) {
            event.preventDefault();
            jQuery('#NextButton').click();
        }
    }
});
```

But the code also affected parts of the survey that I was not interested that the participant can proceed in this way.

I got the following advice:

*If you set up the event with addEventListener() or jQuery on() then you can remove the event in the addOnUnload() function with removeEventListener() or jQuery off().*

but I don't know how to fix the code in accordance.
maybe someone can help me in fixing the code please?

I will be very grateful!

Comment: You have the question id... So I think you could place that event handler inside an `if` statement. Something like `if(qid =="8"){document.onkeydown... }`

Comment: If I understand correctly and `qid` is an element... You would want to add the event listener for the specific element you want it activated on. `let element = document.getElementById(qid); element.addEventListener('keyup', function(event){ // your code})`. For more info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Comment: thanks! `var qid = this.questionId;` which appear in the second line, can help me instead of manually writing the question ID ? @LouysPatriceBessette

Comment: @Dshiz, did you mean for something like that: 
                                        `Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function() {
 let element = document.getElementById(qid); 
 element.addEventListener('keyup', function(event){
  console.log('keydown',event);
  if (event.which == 13) {
   event.preventDefault();
   jQuery('#NextButton').click();
  }

     })
});`

Comment: Yes, but you forgot `var qid = this.questionId;` before the `let element` line. And you could exchange `keyup` with `keydown` if that's your preference.  I'm not familiar with Qualtrics Survey Engine, so I'm not 100% my suggestion will work.

Comment: @Dshiz OK! and for restricting the code I have to add something like `Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnUpload(function() {  
              element.removeEventListener('keydown', function(event))}`, or does the code you wrote to me add the command only locally, and no further restriction is needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the following. The keydown event will only apply to the current survey page.

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function() {
             jQuery(document).keydown(function(event) {
                            if (event.which == 13) {
                                          event.preventDefault();
                                          jQuery('#NextButton').click();
                            }
             });
             Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnUnload(function() {
                            jQuery(document).off('keydown');
             });
});
```

.keydown() is a shortcut for .on('keydown', function()... You don't use qid, so you don't need it. console.log is only for debugging so you don't need that either.